# Wampserver slowing when internet is connected

Tags: performance, response, wampserver

Why my wampserver taking too long time to response when I'm connected to the internet?
But when I disconnected the internet, It's work fine.

Comment: your question is better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that DNS lookups work OK on the machine when connected. Especially for the hostnames you are serving and localhost.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: It's working now. Just changing this file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host, 127.0.0.1 localhost was commented, so I remove the comment and restart the server. Thanks.